# using ng-repeat with google materials flex box (with wrap?)

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to create a 2 by 2 grid iterating with `ng-repeat` and using the flex box. I have seen some examples where `flex-wrap:wrap` attribute would produce the effect I want, but I haven't been able to get the flex-widths to work correctly.

The following is the mark down I have, with screenshots for wide, and mobile view, respectively. I am trying to get the wide view to render a 2x2 box.

```
<div layout="row"  layout-xs="column">

<div layout="row"  layout-xs="row" flex-sm="25"   flex-gt-sm="50"  ng-repeat="sellingPoints in detailCtrl.sellingPointsMenu"   class="selling-points-wrapper">
    <div class="selling-points-picture">
    <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{ sellingPoints.icon }}" aria-label="Expand"></md-icon>
    <div class="selling-points-text">{{ sellingPoints.title }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3EJc.jpg -- wide-view
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gbeO.jpg -- mobile-view

Comment: What, specifically, is your question? For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Comment: My question is - How can I get that ng-repeat, to print out the 4 elements in a 2x2 grid? The image links i provided are what I get output, on desktop-view it was 4 'cards' wide- I want it to print out 2 cards, and 2 on a new row. My apologies if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Yeah, that's better. You should edit your original post, to make it a more final ask. Good job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you want? [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/YGmYBR?editors=1010#0)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column">
  <div style="background:pink" flex="10"></div>
  <div flex="50" layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" style="background:{{item}}; width:50%"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background:grey" flex="10"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.items = ["red", "green", "purple", "orange"];
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for... I was doing mistakingly using 'layout-wrap:wrap'. Thanks alot!!